# c# DataGridView is too slow to redraw display data

Tags: c#, performance, datagridview

I have problems will windows forms being very slow to display and using a lot of CPU so I am trying to optimize graphics piece by piece.

I use DataGridView to display tables of data which I like updating continuously here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataTable myTable;
        private BindingSource mySource;
        private int numrows;
        private int numcols;
        private Random randNum;
        private bool wasActivated;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            numrows = 50;
            numcols = 20;
            randNum = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            myTable = new DataTable();
            mySource = new BindingSource();
            mySource.DataSource = myTable;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = mySource;

            Functions.DoubleBuffered(dataGridView1, true);

            for (int ii = 0; ii < numcols; ii++)
            {
                myTable.Columns.Add((ii+1).ToString(), typeof(double));
            }


            for (int ii = 0; ii < numrows; ii++)
            {
                myTable.Rows.Add();
            }
            timer1.Interval = 200;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (myTable != null)
            {
                //mySource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
                for (int ii = 0; ii < numrows; ii++)
                {
                    for (int jj = 0; jj < numcols; jj++)
                    {
                        myTable.Rows[ii][jj] = randNum.Next(100) / (double)randNum.Next(1, 100000);
                        //dataGridView1.Rows[ii].Cells[jj].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(randNum.Next(256), randNum.Next(256), randNum.Next(256));
                        //dataGridView1.Rows[ii].Cells[jj].Style.BackColor = Color.Empty;
                    }
                }
                //mySource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
                //mySource.ResetBindings(true);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!wasActivated)
            {
                dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
                for (int ii = 0; ii < numrows; ii++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[ii].Height = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height - 2;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[ii].Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;
                }
                dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 50;
                dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
                dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
                for (int ii = 0; ii < numcols; ii++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns[ii].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[ii].Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;

                    dataGridView1.Columns[ii].Width = 80;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[ii].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 11.0F, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                this.Height = dataGridView1.PreferredSize.Height;
                this.Width = dataGridView1.PreferredSize.Width;
                wasActivated = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Functions class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Functions
    {
        public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
        {
            Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
        }
    }
}
```

In the designer I have a form with a datagridview docked in the main form and a timer which is turned on in the code.

The function class is used to enable double buffering on the datagridview using reflection the code found on another page. It definitely makes it look better, but it is still slow.

I only have a 50x20 grid and updating at only 5 fps my CPU is almost pegged.

By comparison I made an excel file with 50x20 random number cells and hold down F9. The CPU gets pegged, but the values display much faster.

Notice that if DoubleBuffering is off, as single refresh takes a noticeable amount of time from the code, but in excel F9 refreshes the screen instantly as far as I can see.

Also, I added a commented out line to randomly change the cell background color which when turned on does not increase CPU usage at all which means that it redraws the background all  the time so I wonder if this can be optimized somehow.

My goal is to be able to display a full update to the table as fast as Excel can.

Comment: Well one thing you can try is to cache the `PropertyInfo` instance in your `Functions` class.  You only need to look it up once, then you'd only have the line with `PropertyInfo.SetValue()` to call.  Amend that and see if you can any more performance improvement.

Comment: Thank you, The PropertyInfo is only used once to enable DoubleBuffering, while it is a great point, it does not help the datagridview to draw any faster (which takes a noticeable amount of time on any machine I tried).

Comment: Have you tried Suspending Layout, updating the values then Resuming the Layout after the update?

Comment: Yes I tried SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout and it is not nearly as effective ad DoubleBuffering. It seems that just drawing the grid takes too long.

Comment: What I do as a test is minimize the form and then restore, without doublebuffering, the main window loads and then I see it render the datagridview from top to bottom (very noticable) with double buffering it is much better, but I am trying to speed up the paint itself which I think is the real issue.

Comment: What is the preferred upload method on SO, id like to upload a zip of my code to show exactly what I mean.

Comment: Have you considered using [virtual mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: @Groo, I have used virtual mode before, but not it this project. Virtual mode only draws content that is on the screen and gives greater, control, however it did not improve paint performance for what was visible. Also, I have a table as a datasource. Which events need to be handled in the case of binding source update?

Comment: Possibly a related issue, I noticed that every time the mySource.ResetBindings(true); it triggers a re-size on the rows. On activate I make the row heights a little smaller but reset binding resets the height to default and I cannot seem to stop it. Is there a sure way to lock the size of the grid after the activated method?